# Can't print anything using pdfbox

Tags: java, pdf, printing, pdfbox

I'm trying use apache's pdfbox to print a pdf file, so I created a controller responsible to print any pdf file. As you can see in the code bellow, the controller has only one public method with file path parameter. The controller runs without exception, but it don't print anything:

```
public class ControladorImpressao {

    @Value("${nome.impressora}")
    private String nomeImpressora;
    private PDDocument arquivoPDF;
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public boolean imprimir(String arquivo) {
        try {
            carregarArquivoPDF(arquivo);
            iniciarImpressao(arquivo);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Erro ao tentar imprimir documento!",e);
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void carregarArquivoPDF(String arquivo) {
        try {
            arquivoPDF=new PDDocument();
            arquivoPDF.load(arquivo);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Erro ao abrir pdf!",e);
        }
    }

    private void iniciarImpressao(String nomeArquivo) throws PrinterException {
        PrintService impressora=recuperarImpressora();
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        job.setPrintService(impressora);
        job.setJobName(nomeArquivo);
        job.setCopies(1);
        arquivoPDF.silentPrint(job);
    }

    private PrintService recuperarImpressora() {
        PrintService[] printServices = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();
        for (int count = 0; count < printServices.length; ++count) {
            if (nomeImpressora.equalsIgnoreCase(printServices[count].getName())) {
                return printServices[count];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm using pdfbox version 1.7.0 with maven:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem changing the way I instatiate PDDocument (now I'm using static load) and changing how I use PrinterJob:

```
public class ControladorImpressao {

    @Value("${nome.impressora}")
    private String nomeImpressora;
    private PDDocument arquivoPDF;
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public boolean imprimir(String arquivo) {
        try {
            arquivoPDF=PDDocument.load(new File(arquivo));
            PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
            job.setPrintService(recuperarImpressora());
            job.setJobName(arquivo);
            job.setPageable(arquivoPDF);
            job.print();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Erro ao tentar imprimir documento!",e);
        }
        return false;
    }

    private PrintService recuperarImpressora() {
        PrintService[] printServices = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();
        for (int count = 0; count < printServices.length; ++count) {
            if (nomeImpressora.equalsIgnoreCase(printServices[count].getName())) {
                return printServices[count];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

A intersting thing I noticed is that if instead ou use static load method I use:

```
arquivoPDF=new PDDocument();
arquivoPDF.load(arquivo);
```

I still can't print anything, probably the problem is in load method.
Thanks to @yms, if he didn't tell me about the note in PdfBox's documentation, probably I would go to another path.